# Sub-query returning more than 1 row: SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sub-query returning more than 1 row.

My current SQL Server query looks like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT AST.AssetName
    ,ReleaseDt
    ,ExpiresDt
    ,TicketNumber
    ,ChangeDt
    ,ChangeReasonCd
FROM pmm.pmmreleaserequest PRR WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN pmm.PmmManagedAccount AS PMA WITH (NOLOCK) ON PRR.ManagedAccountID = PMA.ManagedAccountID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ManagedEntity AS ME WITH (NOLOCK) ON PRR.ManagedSystemID = ME.ManagedEntityID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Asset AS AST WITH (NOLOCK) ON ME.AssetID = AST.AssetID
LEFT JOIN pmm.PmmLogChange AS PLC WITH (NOLOCK) ON PRR.ManagedAccountID = PLC.ManagedAccountID
    AND PRR.ExpiresDt < PLC.ChangeDt
ORDER BY PLC.ChangeDt ASC
```

And currently my output looks like as below.

```
AssetName       ReleaseDt           ExpiresDt           TicketNumber    ChangeDt            ChangeReasonCd    
DummyAsset66    2020-05-02 17:45:38 2020-05-02 17:45:52 dummyticketx1   2020-05-02 17:50:06 U    
***DummyAsset66 2020-05-02 17:45:38 2020-05-02 17:45:52 dummyticketx1   2020-05-02 18:26:06 U***    
DummyAsset66    2020-05-02 18:23:12 2020-05-02 18:23:59 dummyticketx2   2020-05-02 18:26:06 U
```

I don't want to print the second row alone but still need the 3rd row from the output, below Left Join is returning more than one row. I want to take the first row alone.

```
LEFT JOIN pmm.PmmLogChange AS PLC With (nolock) ON PRR.ManagedAccountID = PLC.ManagedAccountID and PRR.ExpiresDt < PLC.ChangeDt
```

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: I can't figure out why you are using `LEFT JOIN`.  Your first column is for the asset name and yet it can be `NULL` with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this correctly, you want to deduplicate your result set by certain set of columns (apparently by `AssetName` and `TicketNumber`). Since SQL Server lacks `DISTINCT ON` operator, I suggest you use the following trick as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808854/sql-server-equivalent-of-postgresql-distinct-on)

You basically populate each row in your projection with row number like this `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY <whatever columns you consider as deduplication keys like AssetName,TicketNumber, ...>)` then filter out all rows with `ROW_NUMBER() > 1` instead of using `DISTINCT` operator. And btw, I agree with @marc_s, you shouldn't be using `NOLOCK` like you do.

But if the problem is only with last join you can replace it with subquery like this `(SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM pmm.PmmLogChange AS PLC WHERE PRR.ManagedAccountID = PLC.ManagedAccountID AND PRR.ExpiresDt < PLC.ChangeDt ORDER BY PLC.ChangeDt ASC) AS mngac`

Comment: LEFT JOIN pmm.PmmLogChange AS PLC With (nolock) ON PRR.ManagedAccountID = PLC.ManagedAccountID and PRR.ExpiresDt < PLC.ChangeDt. this condition returning more then one row and causing issue for me. I want only the first row after order by ASC.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can provide the modified query and send me the query, as am not expert in SQL query language

Comment: is that suppose to be the first arbitrary row from `pmm.PmmLogChange` table that fits your condition? I mean don't you have to select this single row by certain criteria like one with the largest ChangeDt < ExpiresDt or any of those

Comment: right From pmm.PmmLogChange table I have to match first ManagedAccountID which list more then one row and  again compare the ChangeDt should be > then ExpireDt again it will return more then one row Order it by ChangeDt ASC get only the first row

Comment: Syntax Error SELECT DISTINCT AST.AssetName
    ,ReleaseDt ,ExpiresDt,TicketNumber,ChangeDt,ChangeReasonCd
FROM pmm.pmmreleaserequest PRR WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN pmm.PmmManagedAccount AS PMA WITH (NOLOCK) ON PRR.ManagedAccountID = PMA.ManagedAccountID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ManagedEntity AS ME WITH (NOLOCK) ON PRR.ManagedSystemID = ME.ManagedEntityID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Asset AS AST WITH (NOLOCK) ON ME.AssetID = AST.AssetID
(select top 1 ChangeDt from pmm.PmmLogChange AS PLC where PRR.ManagedAccountID = PLC.ManagedAccountID AND PRR.ExpiresDt < PLC.ChangeDt)
ORDER BY PLC.ChangeDt ASC